# Getting two lat-lon points in JSP to find shortest path on click of OpenLayers map?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, shortest-path

I'm  using GeoServer, PostgreSQL and here OpenLayers. I'm trying to retrieve two lat-lon points (for point A and point B) on clicking of map. This code is working only to retrieve one lat-lon.

I want to use this for four (two lat-lon) points in JSP file, that I will use to find shortest path between that points.

So how can I perform this?

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
                defaultHandlerOptions: {
                    'single': true,
                    'double': false,
                    'pixelTolerance': 0,
                    'stopSingle': false,
                    'stopDouble': false
                },

                initialize: function(options) {
                    this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                        {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
                    );
                    OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                        this, arguments
                    ); 
                    this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                        this, {
                            'click': this.trigger
                        }, this.handlerOptions
                    );
                }, 

                trigger: function(e) {
                    var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
                    var lat=lonlat.lat;
                    var lon=lonlat.lon;

                    //alert("You clicked near " + lonlat.lat + " N, " +
                      //                        + lonlat.lon + " E");
                    window.location.replace("atobNewForPath.jsp?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon);

                }
            });

 var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
            map.addControl(click);
            click.activate();
```

In body tag

```
<%
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lat"));
    double lon = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lon"));

/*How to perform this one
    double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lat2"));
    double lon2 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lon2"));
    */

    out.println(lat);
    out.println(lon);


    }%>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to save the previously clicked point in the trigger function?

Comment: exactly and want to use that two point(previous and current) in java tag as variable.

Comment: So, you need to create two more variables inside your overriden Control.Click class, lat_last, lon_last, for example, and update those to previous values of lat/lon, if they exist. Assuming all 4 have values, and are different, then you can call your jsp function.

Comment: i had tried this yesterday <https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkqdfzu7p20v3mj/path.txt?dl=0>

Comment: Above code also not work. 
and my page stucture : 

javascript defer
init()
{
 click event code
 and map creation code
}
<body onload=init()>

Comment: You need to post a full working example.

Comment: Here is full example.
<https://www.dropbox.com/s/bectkc9jybg3lrb/path.jsp?dl=0> 
Plz say corrections asap.

Comment: And now it has one more bug..that if i perform simple modification in trigger block of click control then at run the jsp page shows NOTHING.

Answer (score 0):

## Please try below code. it might be useful in this scenario...

```
var lat1='',lat2='',lon1='',lon2='';var index=0;trigger: function(e) {
                var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
if ( index==0)
{
                 lat1=lonlat.lat;
                 lon1=lonlat.lon;

}else(index==1){
                 lat2=lonlat.lat;
                 lon2=lonlat.lon;
window.location.replace("atobNewForPath.jsp?lat1="+lat+"&lon1="+lon1 + "&lat2="+lat+"&lon2="+lon1);}else{
    alert('Please press reset button');
}
index=index+1;
}
```